# How to provide a custom Deserializer for akka-http query parameters?

Tags: akka-http

The [akka-http 2.4.7 reference](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html) states that it's possible to do custom `Deserializer`s to convert query parameters, without storing them in an intermediate variable:

> `"amount".as[Int]` extract value of parameter "amount" as Int, you need a matching Deserializer in scope for that to work (see also Unmarshalling)
>
> `"amount".as(deserializer)` extract value of parameter "amount" with an explicit Deserializer

However, the [Deserialized parameter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html#Deserialized_parameter) sample on that page does not show how custom deserializers are being used.

How do I define one, so that I can say, e.g. `.as[MyType]`?

I think the documentation is at fault, because I cannot find a `Deserializer` mentioned anywhere in akka sources: [search](https://github.com/akka/akka/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Deserializer)

[image]

*Screenshot on how `Deserializer` is typeset in the Akka docs.*

Answer (score 5):

A `Deserializer` is just a name for an `Unmarshaller` in `akka-http 2.4.7` (same for `akka-http 2.4.8`)

**Edit**: Let's say you're extracting a query parameter named `type`, and you want a `Deserializer` that can pattern-match that `type` parameter from a `String` to a `MyType`.

**Your `route` that's in your server app may look like this:**

```scala
object MyServer {
  ...
  // Assuming that you're requiring a
  // `type` parameter from a `POST` request

  import MyType._

  val route =
    post {
      parameter('type.as(myTypeDeserializer)) { myTypeValue =>
        complete {
          // `myTypeValue` is already pattern-matched
          // to type `MyType` here thanks to `myTypeDeserializer`
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  ...
}
```

**Your `MyType` object may look like this:**

```scala
object MyType {
  case object Type1 extends MyType
  case object Type2 extends MyType
  case object Type3 extends MyType

  import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller

  // Here we pattern match the query parameter,
  // which has type `String`, to a `MyType`
  val stringToMyType = Unmarshaller.strict[String, MyType] {
    case "type1" => MyType.Type1
    case "type2" => MyType.Type2
    case "type3" => MyType.Type3
  }
}
```

Hence `akka-http` will automatically throw a `BadRequest` response if user requests an unsupported `type` parameter.

Comment: I thought they could be the same. But if so, why is `Deserializer` in the code font: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html#Description It implies it's an interface or a class of its own. Also, I want to convert query parameter -> case class, nothing to do with HttpEntities that your sample handles.

Comment: Glad you showed the `Unmarshaller.strict` parameter is actually a partial function. Can use that and it would make my solution (below) also simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to declare the custom query parameter marshaller right, based on the [PredefinedFromStringUnmarshallers.scala](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.7/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/unmarshalling/PredefinedFromStringUnmarshallers.scala) built-in samples.

```
implicit val desId: Unmarshaller[String,Context.Id] = Unmarshaller.strict[String, Context.Id] { s =>
  Context.Id.parseOpt(s).getOrElse(
    if (s=="") throw Unmarshaller.NoContentException
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException( s"Not a valid id: '$s'" )
  )
}
```

Providing the return type explicitly seems to matter.

Comment: The `if (s=="")` could be replaced by a condition in the partial function entry.